# Vuejs didn't install basic html files and folders after creating new Project

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-cli, javascript-framework

please I'm new to Vuejs and after installing Vuejs/CLI i created a new project with `vue create test` then i prompt me to choose between three options which are

```
> Default ([Vue 2] babel, eslint)
  Default (Vue 3 Preview) ([Vue 3] babel, eslint)
  Manually select features
```

then i chose the second option `Default (Vue 3 Preview) ([Vue 3] babel, eslint)`, then it went on to install neccessary dependencies and created the app folder and after done i checked the project directory and the only thing i found there was node_modules, package.json and package_lock.json no default folders and html files was installed and when i ran `npm run serve` it gave me this error

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "serve"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: <dir>
```

and this is my package.json content

```
{
 "name": "test",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
  "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0"
  }
}
```

please what's causing the error

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error as well. Try downloading a older version of node.js like 14.16.0. Sometimes the new node.js version mess up the Vue.js build processess. Hope this helped:)

Comment: OK I'll try that

Comment: that's the version i'm currently using, i just checked it